# Regex: Determine if a character appears before first occurrence of another character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to determine whether or not a certain character appears before the first (and only the first) occurrence of another character.

For example, I want to determine whether the character 'X' appears before the first occurrence of 'Y'.

The regex would match these:

```
acXaaccccYaaacacXacacaY // X appears before the first occurrence of Y
aXacacaXacacXavaY // X appears before the first occurrence of Y
```

The regex would NOT match this:

```
acacacaYacacacXacacacY // The X appears after the first occurrence of Y
```

Is this possible with a single regex match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
^[^Y]*X.*Y.*$
```

In English, that's "A string of non-Ys, then an X, then anything so long as it contains a Y".

Comment: This regex will not work if X is the first character e.g. if you take the 1st example an remove the "ac", "XaaccccYaaacacXacacaY" does not match whereas it should.

Comment: @Fresh Replacing `+` with `*` should solve that, as I did. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: There's an argument that the `.*$` part is superfluous.  The first `.*` could be replaced by `[^Y]*`; I wonder if it should be replaced?  The `.*` will find up to the last (rather than first) Y in the string.

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as this:

```
^[^Y]*X.*Y
```

If you need to match the *whole* input, add `.*`, ie: `^[^Y]*X.*Y.*`

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/q3Alfwo6H4) of this working with your examples.